# Is there a way to get value in first column when record button is clicked in each record

Tags: jquery

I need to get value from from first column when button in the last column of each record is clicked

Each button has different Id(generated dynamically)  in the table and the purpose is to get value in the first   data cell of each record when the button in the last data cell of each row is clicked

This is my code to do this please help

```js
$("button").click(function() {
    var x = $(this.id).parent().find(`td:eq(0)`).html(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: please add html in your snippet to make it running and understandable.

Comment: You're missing the `#` prefix on the `this.id` selector, ie. `$('#' + this.id)`. That being said, it's better to create the jQuery object from `this` directly, eg. `$(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that you have HTML structure like what i have used in my code snippet.(exactly same or similar)

According to that you have to modify your code like below:-

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var x = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').html(); 
    console.log(x);
});
```

Working snippet:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
    var x = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').html(); 
    console.log(x);
    //this one will work too(:first)
    var y = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').html(); 
    console.log(y);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><button type="button">Click Me!</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td><button type="button">Click Me!</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please could you help with last path of the code. I mean the Ajax part as it is not responding. Thanks
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('button.unlock').attr("id",idGenerator("button"))
 
 $("button").click(function() {
      var UserIDCellValue = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').html(); 
    
 
  
 
 
    //console.log(UserIDCellValue);
   $.ajax({
    
  type: "POST"
  url: "deactivated_cs_user.asp"
  data:{UserId:"UserIDCellValue" }
  
 
    });
 
  
});

Comment: @OlayinkaPopoola  for that you have to ask a new question. your current question is already answered. You have to close this question by marking the answer. Please Ask new question with proper input data, your code-effort and explanation about your problem. you will  get help for-sure. You can drop link here too, if will be free i will check and try to answer. Thanks

Comment: Please can you help out with this instead:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56258070/how-to-attribute-of-hyperlink-around-a-button-in-each-record-on-a-table