# How to attribute of hyperlink around a button in each record on a table

Tags: jquery

I've a table with records and each record has a button. My intention is to dynamically set href attribute in the  around each button in each record.

I need to get a value from the first column  of each record to for value attached to each href value in each record.

The table is generated using Vbscript and I intend to set the href value around each record button using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var UserIDCellValue = $(a).find('button').closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').html(); 
    // so for each link around each button  I want to  have something like
    // href ="web/x/y.asp?id= UserIDCellValue "

    // please dont forget that UserIDCellValue is the value in the first column of each record    
});
```

Comment: try to add your html

Comment: You have to provide PROPER input HTML as well as your code-efforts too. otherwise it seems that you are asking us to do code for you. This platform is meant for helping to correct your code, not to write code for you.You have to try code stuff at your end first,and then come-up here with your problem. Thanks. (I am not criticizing you, just trying to tell you the correct way to use this platform)

Comment: I have resolved it and thank you for the advice. I will send my code next time

Comment: @OlayinkaPopoola  either add answer (code which resolved your problem) under answer area or delete your question. Otherwise this question will be open forever and unnecessary answers as well as negative marking on your question will come in near future. You will loose your reputation points because of that

Answer (score 0):

@Alive to Die. Thank you for your advice I really appreciate it. As you can see I am very much new on this platform.

This is how I finally resolved my problem:

"-1"   then                          
    ' Render tabular data


        for c_i = 0 to Rc
            response.write("")

                for  s_i = 0 to UBound(arrRows,1)

                  Response.write(""&arrRows(s_i,c_i)&"")

                    if s_i = 0 then
                      arrval= arrRows(s_i,c_i)
                    end if

                next

    response.write("")

    response.write("")

next


end if     
 %>